# Current Toll Cost XML Data Product HERE API

Tags: here-api

Where can I get the current list of cities/countries where Toll Cost Extension API of HERE MAPS is available?

Comment: You probably will need to contact the official HERE Technical Customer Support to get this info (https://developer.here.com/documentation/toll-cost/topics/coverage-information.html)

Answer (score 0):

Toll Cost information is available with/without price for most of Europe and North America.